# PostgreSQL. Каз задать LIMIT и OFFSET только для одной таблице при JOIN

Tags: sql, psql

Есть две таблицы, student и test. Делаем выборку студентов с их результатами тестов. Вот пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ad0928/2

Как задать LIMIT и OFFSET для первой таблицы student так, чтобы сохранилась возможность сортировки результата как по student так и по test?

Т.е. мне нужно, чтобы количество студентов было, например, 25 штук. Но при этом:

- в выборке видеть так же и тесты которые они проходили (у каждого студента может быть несколько пройденных тестов);
- и иметь возможность отсортировать выборку по набранным баллам за тест.

Исходные таблицы например выглядят так:
[image: исходные таблицы]

И мне нужно получить 4 студентов со всеми их тестами, где студенты с тестом по subject_id = 2 были бы отсортированы по убыванию результата теста.

И вот примерный результат, который хотелось бы получить:
[image: примерный результат]

Comment: Не понимаю что означает задать limit и offset для одной таблицы. они применимы ко всей выборке. приведите более конкретный пример что бы вы хотели например ограничить

Comment: @Mike дополнил вопрос)

Comment: А как у вас Алексей оказался на первом месте, я не вижу что бы он был лидером по score. И собственно если записи на входе должны оказаться в показанном на картинке порядке, где записи одного студента рядом, вне зависимости от поля сортировки, то надо более точно описать критерий сортировки. В данном случае это явно не score. Это может быть какое то условие, которое дает один результат для одного студента, ну скажем суммарный score или максимальный scrore. Когда критерий найден, можно начинать сортировать, а потом нумеровать, скажем dense_rank и отбирать записи с rank <= 4

Comment: @Mike спасибо за dense_rank, с помощью него удалось получить то что надо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    b.subject_id,
    b.user_id,
    b.score,
    DENSE_RANK () OVER (
      ORDER BY a.id
    ) dr -- делаем подсчет по student.id
  FROM
    student as a
    LEFT JOIN test b ON (a.user_id = b.user_id and b.subject_id in (1, 2, 3, 4))
  ORDER BY
    case when b.subject_id = 2 then b.score else 0 end DESC, a.id ASC
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE dr <= 4 -- выбираем только 4 первых студентов
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e2123/13

Результирующая таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]